# Passing Data Between UITableView and Custom Cells and Storing It

Tags: ios, swift, struct, tableview, codable

I'm working on a practice project where the iOS app prints a list of /posts from jsonplaceholder.typicode.com, and when the user selects one a detailed view controller is loaded and further information about that post is displayed (author and number of comments). The latter two come from different endpoints to the first.

As of now, the first api call is made when the main view controller loads, for the list of posts. The body text is passed through the segue when the user taps on a cell as this information needs to be displayed on the detailed view controller, as well as the userId and the Id for that post (for the next api calls). In the detailed view controller, two further api calls are made (one for each endpoint needed), and so all of the data is ready.

As of now, this data is being stored in an array. String, String, Int (author, body and number of comments).

How better can I represent this data as I realise this is a very hacky way to do it? The main view controller / post data is contained within one Post struct, but I'm not sure how to combine the three pieces of separate data in one struct for the detailed view controller.

Please see [Refining Swift API GET Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52447135/refining-swift-api-get-functions) for api calls / structs

```
var userId = 0
var id = 0
var sectionCount = 0
var postDetails = ["", "", ""]

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    populateDetailedTableView()
}

func populateDetailedTableView() {
    APIManager.sharedInstance.getAuthor(for: userId) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let author):
            self.postDetails[0] = author
        case .failure(let error):
           print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    APIManager.sharedInstance.getComments(for: id) { (result) in
        switch result {
        case .success(let comments):
            self.postDetails[2] = "View all \(comments.count) comments"
            self.sectionCount = 3

            CodableService.sharedInstance.savePostDetailsToDisk(postDetails: self.postDetails)
            self.tableView.reloadSections([0], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            self.postDetails = CodableService.sharedInstance.getPostDetailsFromDisk()
            self.sectionCount = 3
            self.tableView.reloadSections([0], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
        }
    }
}
```

And then to display the data:

```
cell.textView.text = postDetails[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: normally the practice is to have an instance variable for your UITableViewController which acts as the datasource. this would in essence be an array of objects that you would access on cellForRowAt where you return a UITableViewCell. I am not sure what the code is above so I am not sure how to answer your question without writing the whole thing.

Comment: It isn't clear exactly what you are asking, but the first step would be to replace the array with a `struct` with appropriate properties.

Comment: Seems like you would like some kind of relationship to be defined between your different models (`Post`, `Author`, `Comment`) for easy access, if I were to do that I would use `CoreData` to store it all (even if I were to clear everything on start/end) combined with `SwiftRecord` to have easy access to CRUD functions and filtering etc. Finally I'd use `SwiftyJSON` for quick and easy parsings of what my different APIs return. Otherwise I agree with @Paulw11 when it isn't clear what you want and that a `struct` would be far better than your array.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, that works. :)